# Images(Media) not displaying on django-heroku server

Tags: python, django, heroku

I had uploaded my site Django app on Heroku server  when I upload image file is successfully uploaded and image path as per settings also fetch properly but the image is not displaying it give error media file not found in a server
 this is settings  media setting

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

this is in url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('UserView.urls')),
    path('caterer/',include('CaterView.urls')),
]
# if settings.MediaAllow:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is models.py

```
class TypeofFood(models.Model):
    tyf_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True)
    tyf_value = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    tyf_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="typeoffood/", null=True, blank=True,default='default.jfif')
```

in template it fatch image like this

```
<center><img src="{{i.tyf_image.url}}" class="img-responsive" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border-radius:50%" alt="Image of Caterers"></center>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

heroku free storage is not allow media file store, that's why your media file will be deleted after upload

because it is like testing purpose, if you want to upload and store media file on heroku you can use third party like `whitenoise`

go to the [link](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/projects/idea-landing/static-files-heroku-django-and-whitenoise) and learn how to use `whitenoise` to upload media file on heroku, you can check [this link](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) also.

happy codding

Comment: thanks, @Nj but I am already using whitenoise  its still not working

Answer (score 6):

For heroku to serve static files you need to add whitenoise package too. Install it and add the necessary configurations.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Simplified static file serving.
    # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "your_static_folder")

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "your_media_folder")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your html, you will have to serve your image like so:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!">
```

The "image.url" format  in the html does not work on staticfiles/Heroku
I ran into a similar issue on Heroku, and solved my issue using these links below.

```
Here is a complete guide for serving images on Heroku:
```

https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/Heroku_Django_Deployment_Guide.md

I would recommend going through the references also. These would be the references:

```
1) http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

2) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

3) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static
```

Answer (score 1):

1-Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

2-In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

3-In your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL for the given relative path using the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```

4-Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example: my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg.

Comment: paths are correct and the path that is coming from uploaded file path is also the correct issue is the file that is not storing in the server it gives server error that file not found

Answer (score 0):

[From the Docs](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
>   the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
>   shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
>   filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
>   container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

Hence you will need to use a third party static file storage service.

Answer (score 0):

`settings.py`

```
DEBUG = True #I got the error beacuse i changed the DEBUG to False

MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
...
]

import os
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/', include('app_name.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```