# How to write dynamic (Django) URLs for serving images using Whitenoise on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, whitenoise

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115062/5965865) here and read the tips [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html?highlight=dynamic%20url#enable-whitenoise) about serving static images. But I'm baffled: The official Whitenoise docs said to write the URLs this way:

```
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!" />
```

And NOT this way:

```
<!-- DON'T WRITE THIS -->
<img src="/static/images/hi.jpg" alt="Hi!" />
```

But if I were to use a dynamic URL, such as `src="{{recipe.image.url}}"`, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, but I don't understand why. So if anyone can explain it, I'll accept that answer. I have two root folders,`static` and `staticfiles`. Each had their own folders `images` and `media`. I removed all the existing images, made changes to the code (see below), and re-uploaded the images--and viola! It worked--and worked on Heroku.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  # Didn't work
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'  # Yes, worked

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'



MEDIA_URL = '/media/'     # Didn't work
MEDIA_URL = '/staticfiles/media/' # Yes, worked

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')     # Didn't work
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/media/')     # Yes, worked
```

Answer (score 0):

The first img tag you had is the correct way of pulling static files from your static directory. Whitenoise simply helps serve images/media files on Heroku servers but it isn't needed for local development. To properly use static, however, you need to load static at the top of each template. Example:

```html
<!-- template.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% load static %}

<!-- show static image -->
<img src="{% static 'images/hi.jpg' %}" alt="Hi!" />

<!-- show dynamically -->
<img src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="{{ item.name }}">

{% endblock %}
```

***Note that the actual path to the image, `images/hi.jpg`, is in single quotes so as to not conflict with the outside double quotes***

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I don't think you understood my question. The examples in my original post were taken from the Whitenoise docs. `{% load static %}` is on every template.

Comment: Ah, just saw your updated answer above. That is pretty unusual for Django static files to do that, the staticfiles directory is mainly for admin css/js and other files. To collect those files you would run `python manage.py collectstatic` but keep in mind it will fully flush out and recreate the directory with new files. One thing I do to change between `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` is by doing an `if DEBUG:` on  `STATICFILES_DIRS` and else I direct to `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: Yes, I noticed `python manage.py collectstatic` collected admin related files and left the media files untouched. Still, it's not clear to me the difference btw the paths (`STATIC_UR`L ) and `root` (`STATIC_URL`), and then `static` vs `staticfiles`. As if that wasn't confusing enough: After I cleared the static and media folders and made changes in settings, a `media` folder was created inside `staticfiles/media`. Question is why.